# Server-side rendering of handlebars.js templates with Django

Tags: django, handlebars.js

Is it possible to render handlebar templates with Django? I am trying to avoid providing two copies of each template that needs to be rendered both server-side and client-side.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/yavorskiy/django-handlebars)?

Comment: @jimw that compiles but doesn't render the templates server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [djangobars](https://github.com/mjumbewu/djangobars). Solves your problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom tag that solves this problem. It iterates through the parser and ignores the handlebars expressions when sandwiched in between {% handlebars %} and {% endhandlebars %}

Check it out: https://github.com/anthonysutardja/Django-Template-Handlebars

Comment: Anthony, I want to actually render the handlebars serverside, not just pass them through.